# Error in header file C++

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this line of code:

```
#ifndef TIME12_H
#define TIME12_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "time24.h"
class time12
{
    private:
    bool pm;
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
public:
    time12();
    time12(bool p, int h, int m, int s);
    time12(time24 a);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, time12 &a);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, time12 &a);
    int get_hours(){ return hours; };
    int get_minutes(){ return minutes; };
    int get_seconds(){ return seconds; };
};

#endif // TIME12_H
```

It gives me the following error on the `time12(time24 a);` line:

```
error: expected ')' before 'a'
```

I am using Code::Blocks IDE with MinGW.

The `time24.h` file is:

```
#ifndef TIME24_H
#define TIME24_H
#include "time12.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class time24
{
private:
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
public:
    time24();
        time24(int h, int m, int s);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, time24 &a);
        friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, time24 &a);
        int get_hours(){ return hours; };
        int get_minutes(){ return minutes; };
        int get_seconds(){ return seconds; };

};

#endif // TIME24_H
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't specify a line number?

Answer (score 1):

If that sort of error shows up on a line like:

```
time12(time24 a);
```

then the usual cause is that the `time24` type has not been defined.

The only three lines containing the `a` token are:

```
time12(time24 a);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, time12 &a);
friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, time12 &a);
```

and the final two of those are internally consistent within the file (`istream`, `ostream` and `time12` all being in existence when you try to use them).

So, the `time24.h` file will probably be the culprit since there's nothing intrinsically wrong with the file you've shown on its own.

---

And, now that you've posted it, my suspicions were correct - your problem has to do with recursive file inclusions.

If you include `time24.h` from your main program, you'll get the error you see.

Here's what happens in that scenario. Your main program includes `time24.h` which, after it creates the `TIME24_H` include guard but *before* it creates the `time24` class, includes `time12.h`.

That header file, in turn, includes `time24.h` again but, because of the aforementioned include guards, that basically does nothing.

Then it creates the `time12` class which *requires* the `time24` class as a parameter to one of it's functions.

However, since `time24` has not yest been created (you're only halfway through that header file), this fails.

The easiest fix is to just not include `time12.h` from `time24.h` since the only dependency seems to go the *other* way. If you eventually *do* want a circular dependency, you can simply declare the class without defining it:

```
class time12;           class time24;
#include "time24.h"     #include "time12.h"
class time12 {          class time24 {
    :                       :
}                       }
```

Then the class will *exist* (be declared) when you need it but in an undefined state.

Comment: @hacker804, why is your `time24.h` including `time12.h` when it uses nothing from it?

Comment: I think I wrote a function that takes a time12 object as an argument but I deleted it and forgot to delete the #include directive.Removing it, the program runs fine.

Thanks

Comment: @hacker804, makes sense, not needed with what you have but I've added to the answer in case you ever need to re-introduce that. I've also moved your other header file into your question since it's better to have everything self-contained. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You're error could be because your function implementations for get_hours() and the others have an extra semi colon at the end of them. You have 
int get_hours(){...};
but you should have 
int get_hours(){...}